# Why can't I position the browsers focus on the svg/div element that I need?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, svg, positioning

Okay, so this is annoying the hell out of me, I have a webpage with a whole bunch of svgs on it (the svg JQuery plugin), I needed the browser to focus on certain ones(horizontally), so I made a simple function to achieve my end:

```
function adjustWindowPos(svg){
    var left = svg.scrollLeft();
    $(document).scrollLeft(left);
}
```

Where the *svg* object is just an object we get via (we draw and shit to is before we do this, so it is rendered):

```
$("#someDivID").svg('get');
```

I've tested this last night and everything worked fine, this morning I come into work and it throws an error in firebug saying:

> TypeError: svg.scrollLeft is not a function

I realize that it can't find the function because the object is an SVG wrapper not a JQuery object per say...but it **worked yesterday**. That's what I don't get (a lot of things, no coffee today).

Comment: what are you passing in adjustWindowPos function??

Comment: Read the question again.

Comment: hey i dont find that function in docs check it http://keith-wood.name/svg.html

Comment: It is in the docs, in the very page you linked...The whole svg thing is solid, nothing wrong with my use of it up until this point.

Comment: i am talking about this function svg.scrollLeft()

Comment: you can not apply jQuery function on svg object ..

Comment: Yes, I know that, I mentioned it in the question...I'm looking for a JQuery wrapper for the svg object that will allow me to do what I want. I found the answer myself anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create jQuery-object that will contain svg DOM-element, that is jQuery wrapper which you are looking for. You can do it several ways using the `$` jQuery function:

- pass a jQuery selector string to it: `$('jquery selector')`;
- pass a DOM object to it;
- get it from already existing jQuery object, if you have one;

Let me suppose that you have an id-selector:

```
var svg = '#id_of_the_svg_element' 

function adjustWindowPos(svg){
    var $svg = $(svg);             // now this is the jQuery object
    var left = $svg.offset().left; // this is its horizontal position relative to the document
    $(document).scrollLeft(left);
}
```